# SSRS error when connecting to an external database

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

When I test my data source connection in Report Manager, I keep on getting the error message below:

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.)

Here is the setup of the SSRS.

The SSRS server is installed and configured in SystemA, but the database is on an external server (let's call it SystemB) within the same network.

The report does not work in the report folders and browser of SystemA. Both servers are in the same domain.

The reports can be executed in Visual Studio just by changing the connection string, but when I deploy and try to run them in the Report Manager (SystemA), it gives me that error above.

Has anyone had a solution to this?

The database version is MS SQL 2012 running in Window Server 2008 R2